# Foreach var overflow

Tags: jsf, foreach

I have a problem with a foreach loop in my web. This is the code:

```
<c:forEach begin="#{myBean.ini}" end="#{myBean.end}" var="i">
       <p>Item <h:outputText value="${i}"/></p>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem comes when ini = 150 and end = 200. It prints Item 28... and lowers instead of Item 150...

A var defined in the foreach loop could take values between -128 and 128, but I need the values ​​exceed that amount, 500 or even 1000.

Any idea?

Thanks :)

Edit: This is basically my bean:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    private int ini;

    private int end;

    /**
     * @return the ini
     */
    public int getIni() {
        return ini;
    }
    /**
     * @param ini the ini to set
     */
    public void setIni(int ini) {
        this.ini = ini;
    }
    /**
     * @return the end
     */
    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    /**
     * @param end the end to set
     */
    public void setEnd(int end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

....
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `myBean` code? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that

java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FormBean {

    private List<Integer> numbers;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 150; i <= 200; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumbers(List<Integer> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }
}
```

xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <ui:repeat value="#{formBean.numbers}" var="i">
            <p>Item <h:outputText value="#{i}"/></p>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to change some code to make it work with my pager but it works perfectly. Thanks :)